# Buffer (unsigned char *) concatenation in C

Tags: objective-c, c

Probably a very easy question for a C developer, however, I'm new to C and I didn't fully grasp all the concepts behind it yet. So, right now, I use this code to concatenate 2 buffers (audioData and silenceData) and then use them to stream some audio:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned char * data;
    UInt32 size;    
} SoundData;

    SoundData audioData;
            audioData.data = audioFiles[currentSoundDataIndex];
            audioData.size = audioFilesSize[currentSoundDataIndex];

    SoundData silenceData;
                silenceData.size = 44100*2*fabs(silenceDuration-0.049f);
                silenceData.data = malloc(silenceData.size);        
                memset(silenceData.data,0,silenceData.size);

                //beat data
    SoundData beatData;
                beatData.size = (audioData.size + silenceData.size);    
                beatData.data = malloc(beatData.size);

                for (int i=0; i<audioData.size; i++) {
                    beatData.data[i] = audioData.data[i];
                }

                for (int i=audioData.size; i<beatData.size; i++) {
                    beatData.data[i] = silenceData.data[i-audioData.size];
                }
```

This works fine, but I have the feeling that there must be a better way to do it, some built in function maybe?

Comment: Well `memcpy` would probably be useful.

Comment: Strange enough, because I did try it, it failed to work(the sound was completely altered!), maybe I didn't used properly , although it's pretty straight forward, will try again however...

Comment: Why C++ tag? The C++ solution would be rather different.

Comment: I removed the `C++` tag.  There's nothing C++-specific in this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would definitely use `memcpy()` ... it's going to be much faster since that standard library function uses compiler intrinsics or hand-coded assembly in order to greatly speed up the copying of one buffer of bytes to another buffer to the extent that it can be optimized for your processor's platform.  That's much faster than a for-loop ...

So for example:

```
unsigned char* temp_buffer_loc = beatData.data;
memcpy(temp_buffer_loc, audioData.data, audioData.size);

//now put silence data at the end of the buffer
temp_buffer_loc += audioData.size;
memset(temp_buffer_loc, 0, silenceData.size);
```

Comment: This worked like a charm (although I'm sure any of the above solutions would have), but I like it best because it uses memset on a known number of bytes, instead of malloc-ing the silence buffer, which makes the code looks better(less code) and probably it's a optimization as well (?)

Comment: Well, the main optimization is the fact that these standard library memory functions typically use assembly to-do the heavy work under-the-hood.  What would require a number of assembly code lines for a for-loop (including a code branch for the loop-test) can be quickly distilled down into about three or four commands to setup the source address, destination address, number of times to copy, and/or what to fill the buffer with.  So for simple memory copying functions, you loose a lot of speed hand-coding loops.  Loops can be optimized, but they're not going to be as fast as specific commands.

Comment: BTW, yes, not having to allocate and then copy a buffer of zeros from `silenceData.data` to `beatData.data` is going to save some CPU cycles

Comment: Cool, I'm copying a fair amount of data, and I don't know if it's because of memset/memcpy added instead of those for's, because I did some other changes as well, but the app it's really moving better! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

For once, instead of using loop, you can use memcpy, which is much faster, i.e.:

```
memcpy(beatData.data, audioData.data, audioData.size);
```

Comment: I'd use `memmove()`; it always works.  It is safe in this context to use `memcpy()`, but since it does not always work, I prefer the greater safety of using `memmove()`.  YMMV.

Comment: OK, will try it, however, I did try it before and the sound was altered, probably I didn't used as it should, will try again and update question!

Comment: @ Jonathan Leffler ok....noob question, why would memcpy not work in some situations?

Comment: @mindnoise, `memcpy` is not guaranteed to work correctly when the source and the destination blocks are overlapping.

Comment: @Jonathan: I take it you didn't write Adobe Flash Player ]:->

Comment: Out of curiosity, is memcpy faster or slower than memmove? I know that under normal circumstances I shouldn't worry about that, still, I'm curious!

Comment: Well AFAIK memcpy is faster than memmove since memmove checks and handles overlap, but it might not be accurate.

Comment: It's obviously faster.  That's the reason to have it in the first place.  Otherwise why would you have a function that is slower and not as safe to use.  Speed is what you get for sacrificing some flexibility.  Another question is how much speed.  Could be that on modern CPUs the difference is negligible and it's not worth the possible bugs.

Answer (score 2):

It would make sense to replace those `for` loops with `memcpy`.  Otherwise it's ok.

```
memcpy(beatData.data, audioData.data, audioData.size);
memcpy(beatData.data + audioData.size, silenceData.data, silenceData.size);
```

Actually, the silence data you're creating is just a bunch of zeros.  It should be really stored just to be appended to another buffer later.  So second `memcpy` should be replaced with `memset` instead.

```
memcpy(beatData.data, audioData.data, audioData.size);
memcpy(beatData.data + audioData.size, 0, beatData.size - audioData.size);
```